# How do I upload cycles materials in sketchfab while retaining the materials

Tags: materials

Assuming that sketchfab does not support the renders of cycles, i'm not sure how I can upload this file without losing the materials esp when exporting in FBX.

Here is what I want the output to look like (with glass bsdf as the main material used for the whole scene along with custom nodes for the platform)

[image]

I get this instead

[image]

Is there a way for me to upload the model while retaining the appearance and settings of the materials?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Im not sure how I can apply the glossiness of my materials as UV textures.

Comment: this might help too https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202600873-Materials-and-Textures